# New Super mario, How do you get past world 8 tower with mini sized Mario?

Tags: new-super-mario-bros

I have reached the World 8 Tower with micro sized Mario but am not able to kill the last monster that throws tortoise shells. With normal sized Mario we could just throw back the shells to kill it. Can someone please help me, how do I get past it with mini sized Mario [ Please see the screenshot attached ]? [image: Screenshot showing tortoise shell monster and small Mario]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ground Pound.

Mini Mario is only allowed to kill enemies if he jumps in the air and uses ground pound. This could work the same with bosses but watch out for bosses that will kill you if you do jump onto its head/back. The blue things on the top corners seem might lower down to confine the space you can go. This can be token as an advantage by jumping and allowing the shells to rebound off the walls and hit the boss until it dies.

You can also save another power-up like Fire Mario, which force Mario to become his normal size. Having another Mini Mushroom as backup will not help at all since you already are mini-sized... Anyways, watch out for any shells and jump over them or you will become a bite sized snack!